# Do return statements in C++ have a type?

Tags: c++, types, return

As we know, in C++ every expressions and statements have a type. So, what is the type of a return statement in a `void` function? Is its type `void`?

Comment: _"**In C++ is there any type of return statement in a void function?**"_ Yes, there is: `return;`

Comment: "In C++ every expressions and statements have a type." They do? Where did you read that? `break` doesn't have a type. `for (;;);` doesn't have a type either. And many other statements don't have a type.

Comment: @NikosC. That is true for expressions. For statements though, I don't think so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't think this question is a dupe of your suggested dupe; although it may be a dupe of something else.

Comment: @einpoklum It still answers the question. There's obviously _no type_ given along the `return;` statement.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how how would you capture the return value of the `return` statement? The `return` statement itself doesn't actually return.

Comment: @HAL9000 Of course it returns. What are you talking about?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, calling `return` makes the *function* return, but there is nothing in `c` that lets the program jump back to where you called the `return` statement with a return value. Therefore, talking about the type of `return` is somewhat silly. Basically this doesn't make sense: `a=return x;`, or `foo(return x);`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ (and in C), only expressions have types; not statements. However, many statements are actually just evaluations of expressions (e.g. a function call, or an assignment) which may be the cause of confusion.

So, no, a `return` statement - in a function returning void or anything else - has no type as such.

Read more about "expression statements" and statements in general on the [statements page on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements).